# angular translate, how to get all the translate of one specific word in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I know that in controller I can use `$translate.instant('HELLO_WORLD')`, to get the translate to the 'current' set language.

What if the current is french, and I want to get english of 'HELLO_WORLD' too, but not changing the user's current preferred language.

The reason I want this is casue my app let user switch between french and english at any time. Everything works except for a directive that uses a `$rootScope.object`, the words inside doesnt get updated when user change the language.

The way Im trying to do it by is, I use a listener on this rootScope.object, when it get change, I manually change the item inside. However I need to know both french and english translate of each word to make the comparison and change.

Answer (score 0):

The `$translate.instant()` API has a force language parameter. If you know your supported languages ahead of time you could query them all using separate calls to .instant().

`instant(translationId, interpolateParams, interpolationId, forceLanguage, sanitizeStrategy)`